# I am very confused by the solution to a problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I stumbled upon a solution to the so-called "The Math Problem of the Month" for October 2018. 
https://www.aus.edu/sites/default/files/PastProblems_October18.pdf

Now, I have to admit I am very confused by the last few steps.

It says there:

"If $n$ is a multiple of $3$, then $2^{7n}-1$ has the factor $2^{3}-1$"

How do you get the factor out of there? If you set $n=3$ for example,you get $2^{7*3}-1$, but you can't factor out $2^{3}-1$, so what is the method behind that argument?

"When $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, it is easy to see that $7$ does not divide $2^{7n}-1$"

Why? Because you can't extract the factor which you couldn't do in the first place?

"A similar argument shows that

There are $2*953$ values for $m= 1, 2$"

First, shouldn't it be $m=1,3$?

Second, shouldn't it be $2*476$ or am I completely missing something here?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you read about [Mersenne Primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) the first important fact you'll come to  is that the primality of $2^n-1$ implies the primality of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^7\equiv2\pmod7$

$2^{7n}=(2^7)^n\equiv2^n\pmod7$

Now $2^1\equiv2,2^2\equiv4,2^3\equiv1\pmod7$

Comment: And how can you show the opposite,namely if $n$ is not a multiple of three, then $2^{7n}$ is not congruent to 1 mod 7 ?

Comment: As shown in this answer, $2^{7(3a+b)} \equiv 2^{3a+b} \equiv (2^3)^a\cdot2^b \equiv 1^a\cdot2^b \equiv 2^b \pmod 7,$ so if $b=1$ or $2$ then  $2^{7(3a+b)}$ has remainder $2^1$ or $2^4$ when divided by $7.$

Comment: @PhysicsGuy, Generalization : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Answer (score 0):

In general,
$$ x^r - 1 = (x^{r-1} + x^{r-2} + \cdots + x^2 + x + 1)(x - 1). $$

So $ x^r - 1$ has a factor $x - 1.$

Now let $n$ be divisible by $3,$ so $n = 3k,$ and set $x = 2^3$
and $r = 7k.$
Then
$$ 2^{7n} - 1 =  (2^3)^{7k} - 1 = x^r - 1, $$
which has a factor $x - 1 = 2^3 - 1.$

Is it "easy" to see that if $n$ is not divisible by $3$ then 
$2^{7n} - 1$ is not divisible by $7$? Yes, if you follow the modulo-$7$ arithmetic from [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3045477) to its logical conclusion. I don't think it is very well explained in the posted solution at https://www.aus.edu/sites/default/files/PastProblems_October18.pdf.

I agree the "$m = 1$ or $2$" part should be $m = 1,3.$
It is not so clear how the argument for either of these cases
is "similar" to the argument already given.

Comment: And how can you show the opposite,namely if $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, then $2^{7n}-1$ is not a multiple of 7?

Comment: Updated to discuss that part. I think lab's answer is a better approach.